# How to calculate hessian of <Ax, x> / <x, x>

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I need to calculate the gradient and hessian of a function $\frac{\langle Ax, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle}$ where $A$ is a symmetric real matrix. I am a bit familiar with matrix derivatives, so I hopefully calculated the differential correctly
$$
dR = \left \langle \frac{2Ax}{\langle x, x \rangle}  - \frac{2x\langle Ax, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle^2}, dx \right \rangle = \langle \nabla R(x), dx \rangle
$$
But I am completely lost with hessian. I don't understand how I can derive it and move $d_2$ and $d_1$ on correct places and preserve the correct sizes of factors. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\RR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
$Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

Then consider the following scalar functions and their differentials.
$$\eqalign{
\a &= A:xx^T &\qiq &d\a=2Ax:dx,\quad&A^T=A \\
\b &= B:xx^T &\qiq &d\b=2Bx:dx,\quad&B^T=B \\
}$$
Use these to rewrite your objective function,
then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \b^{-1}\a \\
d\l &= \b^{-2}\LR{\b\,d\a-\a\,d\b} \\
 &= \b^{-1}\LR{2Ax-2\l Bx}:dx \\
\grad{\l}{x} &= 2\b^{-1}\LR{A-\l B}x \;\;\doteq\;\; g \\
}$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2\b^{-1}\LR{A-\l B}\RR{dx}
  - 2\b^{-1}Bx\RR{d\l} 
  + 2\LR{A-\l B}x\RR{d\b^{-1}} \\
 &= 2\b^{-1}\LR{A-\l B}dx -2\b^{-1}\LR{Bx}g^Tdx
  - \LR{\b g}\,\b^{-2}\LR{2Bx}^Tdx \\
 &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{A-\l B -{Bx}g^T -gx^TB}\,dx \\
\grad{g}{x} &= 2\b^{-1}\BR{A-\l B -{Bx}g^T -gx^TB} \;\;\doteq\;\; H \\
}$$
So that's the Hessian.
Obviously you are interested in the case where $B=I$.

To reduce some of the expressions above, the following relationships were utilized
$$\eqalign{
&d\l = g:dx \;=\; g^Tdx \\
&d\b^{-1} = -\b^{-2}d\b \;\;=\ -\b^{-2}\LR{2Bx}^Tdx \\
}$$